# "I would love to if I can" vs. "I would love to if I could"

Tags: subjunctives

> - I would love to if I can
> - I would love to if I could

Which one is right?

Comment: It should be *I would love to if I could* imo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*I would love to if I could* has *CAN* in the past tense but with present reference as a counterfactual:

> SHE: Hey, Marco, we're going to the Thai place for lunch, you wanna come with?
>   YOU: I'd love to if I could, but I'm waiting for a call.

*I would love to if I can* has *CAN* in the present tense but with future reference as a contingent possibility:

> SHE: Hey, Marco, we're going to Spiro's after work, you wanna come with?
>   YOU: I'd love to if I can, but right now I don't know how late I'm gonna hafta work.

Answer (score 2):

> I would love to if I could

indicates a possibility in case another possibility occurs. This should be the better choice. The context as used in a full sentence may be helpful.

> I would love to if I can

indicates a possibility in case some ability exists.

*Can* indicates ability while *could* indicates possibility.

So you can say

> I would love to if I could find a babysitter for the kids.

But if you say

> I would love to if I can get an A on the test.

technically might be OK, but it sounds strange.

Comment: I dunno.  If somebody asks me to a party and I decide I can only go if I get my homework done first, when they say, "Hey, do you want to go to the party?" I would respond, "I would love to if I can get my work done in time."  Nothing strange about that.  In fact, using *could* there, implies that you don't think it would be possible.

Comment: @Jim, if you are using could, does it change the meaning of your sentence? 'I would love to if I could get my work done in time.'